# How to set Max User List Count for profile-mgt.jsp

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos, wso2-identity-server

For wso2stratos-is-1.5.1 how can I customize the maximum returned list of results in a HybridLDAP System. I want to return the complete list of results from a ldap query.

Specifically I am looking at the org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui-3.2.0.jar/web/profile/profile-mgt.jsp

This is also seen in the /src/main/resources/web/user/user-mgt.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to get the results I wanted.

I opened up the mysql database userstore and edited the field um_user_config in the table um_tenant.  The data in that field is xml. I found the property for MaxUserNameListLength and changed its value from 100 to a greater number. Then I restarted wso2stratos and was successful in retrieving a larger number of records.